# RLE sequence, setting a value

Tags: java, arraylist, run-length-encoding

Say I have an arbitrary RLE Sequence. (For those who don't know, RLE compresses an array like [4 4 4 4 4 6 6 1 1] into [(5,4) (2,6) (2,1)]. First comes the number of a particular integer in a run, then the number itself.)

How can I determine an algorithm to set a value at a given index without decompressing the whole thing? For example, if you do set(0,1) the RLE would become [(1,1) (4,4) (2,6) (2,1)]. (In set, the first value is the index, the second is the value)

Also, I've divided this compressed sequence into an ArrayList of Entries. That is, each Entry is one of these: (1,1) where it has an amount and value.

I'm trying to find an efficient way to do this, right now I can just think of methods that have WAY too many if statements to be considered clean. There are so many possible variations: for example, if the given value splits an existing entry, or if it has the same value as an existing entry, etc...

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm working on an algorithm now, here is some of it:

```
while(i<rleAL.size() && count != index)
    {
        indexToStop=0;
        while(count<index || indexToStop == rleAL.get(i).getAmount())
        {
            count++;
            indexToStop++;
        }

        if(count != index)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
```

As you can see this is getting increasingly sloppy...

Thanks!

Comment: It might be better to use a linked list instead of an ArrayList, for performance reasons.

Comment: Even though I will have to remove an entry at an index?

Comment: @user977036: +1 but...  Unless you keep additional information you'll have to potentially decompress a lot.  For example if your picture has 10000 pixels and you want to set the 5000 pixels, then no matter if you start from the beginning or try to "get smart" by starting from the bottom, you'll have to decompress half the pixels.  So either you keep somehow track of various indexes or you'll need to decompress quite a lot to do what you want to do (if I'm not mistaken).  If you have to do several such changes, than you could index while decompressing once and then doing all your inserts.

Comment: @user988052 I'm a little unclear - the goal is to not decompress at all. What is the additional information you mention? Also, I only have to change one entry at a time, not en masse.

Comment: @user977036: *"the goal is to not decompress at all"* <-- what do you mean exactly?  You *can* avoid keeping the entire decompressed data in memory but you cannot avoid walking through the data.  I mean, it's kinda the point of RLE: to compress and be relatively small.  If you want to access/change the data, you must decompress...  Unless you've got control on the algorithm and come with something that contains more data (but is hence bigger than the typical RLE).

Comment: @user988052 But I think there is probably some way to avoid decompressing when setting a single value, that's why I'm asking my question

Answer (score 1):

RLE is generally bad at updates, exactly for the reason stated. Changing ArrayList to LinkedList won't help much, as LinkedList is awfully slow in everything but inserts (and even with inserts you must already hold a reference to a specific location using e.g. ListIterator).

Talking about the original question, though, there's no need to decompress all. All you need is find the right place (summing up the counts), which is linear-time (consider skip list to make it faster) after which you'll have just four options:

1. You're in a block, and this block is the same as a number you're trying to save.
2. You're inside a block, and the number is different.
3. You're in the beginning or the end of the block, the number differs from the block's but same as neighbour has.
4. You're in the beginning or the end of the block, the number is neither the same as block's nor the one of neighbour's.

The actions are the same, obviously:

1. Do nothing
2. Change counter in the block, add two blocks
3. Change counters in two blocks
4. Change counter in one block, insert a new one

(Note though if you have skip lists, you must update those as well.)

Update: it gets more interesting if the block to update is of length 1, true. Still, it all stays as trivial: in any case, the changes are limited to maximum of three blocks.